# Determine the Batch input shape

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

This is a part of my code:

```
 def lstm_model_structure(training_data,batch_size, num_neurons):    
      train, test = training_data[:, :8], training_data[:, 8:14]   
      train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], 1, train.shape[1])    
      model = Sequential()
      model.add(LSTM(units=num_neurons,activation="tanh", kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01), name='input',return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
      model.add(Dropout(0.2))
      model.add(LSTM(units=50, name='lstm1',return_sequences=True))
      model.add(Dropout(0.2))
      model.add(LSTM(units=50, name='lstm2'))
      model.add(Dropout(0.2))
      model.add(Dense(6))
      # Compile the model
      adaDelta = optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=0.001, decay=1e-6)
      model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="adaDelta") 
      model.fit(trainX, trainy,validation_data=(testX, testy), epochs=350, batch_size=7, verbose=1, shuffle=False)

return model
```

Where **the shape of training_data is (9,16), batch size is 9, num_neurons is 52.**

The previous model works fine(Without validation data) **but** when i split the data in order to have validation data as following:

```
def lstm_model_structure(training_data,batch_size, num_neurons):        
     train, test = training_data[:, :8], training_data[:, 8:14]
     trainX, testX = train[:7, :], train[7:, :]
     trainy, testy = test[:7], test[7:]
     trainX = trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]) 
     testX = testX.reshape(testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1])
     model = Sequential()
     model.add(LSTM(units=num_neurons, activation="tanh", kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01), name='input',return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
     model.add(Dropout(0.2))
     model.add(LSTM(units=50, name='lstm1',return_sequences=True))
     model.add(Dropout(0.2))
     model.add(LSTM(units=50, name='lstm2'))
     model.add(Dropout(0.2))
     model.add(Dense(6))
     # Compile the model
     adaDelta = optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=0.001, decay=1e-6)
     model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="adaDelta")
     model.fit(trainX, trainy,validation_data=(testX, testy), epochs=350, batch_size=7, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
return model
```

**Where:**

```
     print(trainX.shape) >> (7, 1, 8)
     print(trainy.shape) >> (7, 6)
     print(testX.shape)  >> (2, 1, 8)
     print(testy.shape)  >> (2, 6)
```

I got the following error when i fit the model (Incompatible shapes):

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [7] vs. [9]
     [[{{node training_2/Adadelta/gradients/loss_2/dense_3_loss/mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/mul_grad/Mul_1}}]]
```

How can i determine the correct batch input shape?

Comment: this does not tell use anything, try to print the shape of all these trainX, trainy, testX, testy and share here.

Comment: @faheem I added the shape, please refer to them. Thank you

Comment: i think the issue is batch size, dont specify batch_input_shape in LSTM, you can only specify input_shape.

Comment: also dont write adaDelta as "adaDelta" it is variable now so, remove the inverted commas. `model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adaDelta)`